# R: Anything faster than outer()?

Tags: r, outer-join

Using R, I need to evaluate an expression of the form [using latex notation]

```
\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n f(x_i-x_j),
```

where `x_i,x_j` are real (scalar) numbers and `f` is a nonlinear function with scalar input and output.

My current best [now using R commands] is

```
mat <- outer(x,x,function(y,z) f(y-z))
res <- mean(mat)
```

where `x` is a vector of length `n` which holds all the `x_i`'s.

For `n = 10000`, this operation takes about 26 seconds on my PC, but (as expected) computation time increases heavily in `n`. I'd like to speed this up, mainly because I want to pass the above result to an optimizer later on. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Please provide `f`. You should profile your code (see `?Rprof`). Anyway, `y` and `z` are of length n^2 when passed to the anonymous function. That's pretty long. You could calculate `outer(x,x,"-")` and pass only the upper triangle to `f`.

Comment: @TWL `Vectorize` is just a wrapper around `mapply` (an R loop) and doesn't improve performance. Also, `outer` only accepts vectorized functions; so `f` is already vectorized.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @Roland. `f` looks as follows:               `f <- function(x){
  return(2*dnorm(x)+x*(2*pnorm(x)-1))
}`, so it can be applied to scalars, vectors and matrices alike.

Comment: Well, `x <- rnorm(1e8); system.time(dnorm(x))` gives me a timing of more than 9s seconds. So, `dnorm` and `pnorm` are your bottlenecks.

Comment: Ah...I'll try to enter `dnorm` myself, this is a fairly simple exponential expression. `pnorm` will be harder, since it involves numerical integration. Given how standard these expressions are, I would expect the R implementations to be fairly efficient, though.

Comment: They are efficient (they are written in C). You could also try and parallelize (do the computations in chunks). That might also help against memory problems.

Comment: Good to know they're in C! Do you think it would make sense to try implementing something like `outer` via Rcpp or RcppArmadillo? If yes, do you know which level of C++ expertise is required for these packages?

Comment: I don't think that will help much. As I said your bottleneck is already written in C and strongly optimized. You should reconsider your whole approach. If you don't want that you can (i) avoid calculating duplicated values and (ii) parallelize.

Comment: I computed `outer(x,x,"-")` and summed only over the diagonal and upper-diagonal values. This didn't help much (even increased computation time, probably due to the time it takes to pick out the values). I guess the inefficiency lies in calculating these values in the first place (via `outer`), not in summing over them. Will look into parallelization next.

Comment: Well, how did you select the values? `diag` und `upper.tri` are really fast.

Comment: I used these commands. For a simpler example, try this: `x <- rnorm(10000) > x <- outer(x,x,function(y,z) (y-z)^2) > system.time(sum(x)) > system.time(sum(diag(x))+2*sum(x[upper.tri(x)]))`